# AWS Amplify Auth login is not persistent between app launches?

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

I am configuring AWS Amplify this way:

```
do {
    Amplify.Logging.logLevel = .verbose
    try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
    try Amplify.add(plugin: AWSS3StoragePlugin())
    try Amplify.add(plugin: apiPlugin)
    try Amplify.configure()
    print("Initialized Amplify")
} catch {
    print("Could not initialize Amplify: \(error)")
}
```

After I check if the user is signed in like this:

```
do {
    let session = try await Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()
    switch session.isSignedIn {
    case true:
        DZLog("Signed in")
    case false:
        DZLog("Not signed in")
    }
} catch {
    DZError("Error while fetching session", error: error)
}
```

And I login with this:

```
do {
    let options = AuthWebUISignInRequest.Options(scopes: ["openid", "email", "profile", "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"], pluginOptions: AuthWebUISignInRequest.Options.preferPrivateSession())
    let signInResult = try await Amplify.Auth.signInWithWebUI(for: .apple, presentationAnchor: window, options: options)
    if signInResult.isSignedIn {
        print("Sign in succeeded")
    }
} catch let error as AuthError {
    DZError("Error in signin", error:error)
} catch {
    DZError("Error in signin", error:error)
}
```

If I relaunch the app and check if the user is signed in with *Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()* it always return as not signed in.

Why is the login session not persistent between app launches?